# Polytime programming

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, linear-programming, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

Given a linear system of the form:

$$x_r  = a$$
$$x_j = b$$
$$c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 ... c_nx_n = n$$
$$x_1 + x_2  + x_3 ... x_n = k $$
$$0 \leq a,b,x_1, x_2, x_3 ... x_n \leq 1$$
$$k \geq 0$$
How quickly can the feasibility of the system be checked? To clarify: $x_r, x_j$ are members of ${x_1, x_2 ... x_n}$. Would it be $O(n^{3.5})$ since I believe that is the general complexity for running a linear program or would it be less? Can one use gaussian elimination to quickly reduce the first 4 equations in $O(n^{3})$ and after that systematically move through the equations starting from the terms with largest coefficient and moving to terms with smallest coefficient assigning values that bring the equations as close to satisfactory as possible?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is also a good choice to post in.

Comment: One question, what do you mean by checking the feasibility of the system?

Comment: give a yes or no if the system described is feasible

Comment: It can definitely be solved in $O(n^{3.5})$ since we are free to relax one of the variables $x_r$ or $x_j$ and then optimize the value $x_r - a$ or $x_j - b$ with the additional constraint $x_r - a$ or $x_j - b$ is greater than $0$. So my question is whether this can be done in faster than $O(n^{3.5})$